# How can I access a variable declared within a wrapped function in the global scope?

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm working on a Drupal library that uses two JS files — one internal to create a settings object and another external (a vendor library).

Here's the local file that creates `_settingsObject` with Drupal's required wrapper.

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
      attach: function (context, settings) {
        _settingsObject = {
            ...
        };
      }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The only issue I'm having is that the other file is unable to see this object and I'm not able to access it in the console. How can I make this object available in the global scope?

Thank you!

Comment: Assign a reference to it on the `window` object?

Comment: Where is the *declaration* of the `_settingsObject` variable? The code you posted only assigns to it, but in strict mode that will cause an exception when the variable has not been declared.

Comment: When exactly is `Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior.attach` called? Are you sure you're not trying to access the variable before it had been initialised? Please post the code of the other file as well.

Comment: Are you even loading the script in the correct scope? We need more code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to the window object. Do it like this:

```
(function ($, window) {
    'use strict';
    window.globalVar = "My Global Var";
     Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
       attach: function (context, settings) {
         _settingsObject = {
              ...
         };
       }
    };
})(jQuery, window);
```

Comment: It seems like OP wants `window._settingsObject`, not `window.globalVar`?

Answer (score -1):

The reason, as you hinted at, is due to scope. I'm not 100% this will work because I don't know enough about the function, but it looks like what it is doing (correct me if I'm wrong) is adding `_settingsObject` to the Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior object, such that when you call it you would call Drupal.behaviors.... If this is the case, try returning the object at the end of the function.

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
      attach: function (context, settings) {
        const _settingsObject = {
            ...
        };
        return _settingsObject;
      }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

If that is not the case, please revise your question to include more code, and what exactly you  are calling in the other file and how you are calling it. If you are trying to get the object called _settingsObject you need to return it and make it accessible from the namespace in global scope.